# WKWebView goBack(_:) evaluateJavaScript Fails if going back more than 2 in history

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a function that goes back in my WKWebView history. This is working as expected except when going back more than 2 in history. At this point the `evaluateJavasScript` functionality no longer happens on the correct history item.

```
func backButtonClicked() {
    webView.goBack()

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("arrivedFromBackButton()") { (response, error) -> Void in
        print(response) // webpage outputs the title of the page
    }
}
```

The page titles in order are : Main -> User Info -> Details -> History

if on "History" and I the `backButtonClicked()`is called over and over again this output happens:

1. Details
2. User Info
3. User Info

`evaluateJavaScript` seems to be happening on the previous page, but only when I attempt to go back 3 or more places in history. Does anyone have any ideas as to what would be causing this? I've wrapped the `evaluateJavaScript` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` just to make sure it's on the same thread, but still not having any luck.

Comment: I think it is because WKWebView is non blocking, what that means is that it loads the request in background queue and displays it in main queue. Even though you use evaluateJavascript, I think you would need to do your calls inside window.onload inside your javascript

Comment: @sandeep are you saying that my evaluateJavaScript should have the window.onload in it, or that my javaScript on the page itself should use the `window.load = function(e)` around all of the pages javascript functionality?

Comment: Your evaluateJavascript can have it and then you would wrap backButtonClicked there. Give it a try

Comment: @Sandeep I couldn't get your solution to work properly either. Unfortunately my results were still the same. I however found that I should just use the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) ` as it's also called at the end of the `goBack(_:)` function. I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing though, but it does work.

Comment: You should basically run your JS after the page finishes loading. I think it is best to use that delegate method. BTW, my js document.onload does exactly same from javascript but if it didnt work then you should run JS from the delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` seems to have cleared up my issue. It's called at the end of the `goBack(_:)` function as well. I just had to create a boolean var that could be checked to see if it should fire `evaluateJavaScript`

Comment: @ShauketSheikh the `goBack` function returns a new navigation to the requested item - `WKNavigation` object which is also passed to the navigation delegate methods which does call the `didFinish` in the tracking load progress section of the delegate. [goBack function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414952-goback), [WKNavigation object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigation), [WKNavigationDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

Comment: You have to call yourself did finish function on the base of wknavigation exist or not , if it not exists you can not handle your setting button appearance on back screen. So for that you again need to write your own implementation.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh correct, it would based on if the `wknavigation` existing or not. In this case we're not concerned about that at all, but if it does exist the `didFinish` delegate function is called and any additional functionality can be in there. Thanks for the input.

Comment: If wknavigation exist still didfinish not called. You have to call it forcibly